# Can I simulate a clock without an RTC connected?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, timers, electronics

I want to program for a timer that works as set timer such as in an oven where user can set their own time. One of the way I know is using an IC(RTC) for the timer. However, I don't have the IC yet only the coding and Arduino.

Is it possible to simulate the Arduino code without having the RTC? Or is there any electrical component that I can use to replace the IC for the time being?
Thank you for your help and comment.I really appreciate that.

Comment: You can, by using [`millis()`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/), if you can tolerate the mediocre frequency accuracy of the ceramic resonator clocking the Arduino.

Comment: Yes, if you don't mind if your cake cooks for 1 hour or 1 hour and 5 seconds. :)

Comment: Are you referring to a RTC (Real Time Clock) chip?

Comment: Reply to Majenko: Yes the RTC chip.

Answer (score 2):

TimeLib.h has a virtual clock that can be updated and corrected from multiple sources, including an RTC chip or an NTP server on the internet (assuming an internet connection).

It doesn't *need* that clock source, though, but it will drift with time. Once you have set the clock correctly it will keep close to the right time (assuming no reset or power loss of the Arduino). Not perfect (because the Arduino's main clock isn't perfect) but close enough for many simple applications.

Answer (score 0):

There are programs to simulate Arduino code, but they are very limited. To really simulate the circuit the program would have to also know about the IC you are using. You didn't told us what IC this is, so we can only speculate, that it might not be something, that these programs know (though you can try it). And sometimes Arduino Simulators have problems with simulating time sensitive code. If you want to try, just google for Arduino Simulator and check out the possibilities. I cannot suggest one, since I didn't use one until now.

At this point it might be the better option to write time-keeping code using the `millis()` function, which returns the number of milliseconds since the Arduino started. Save a timestamp from when you started and compare the difference between `millis()` and your timestamp to the wanted bake time.

You can pack this code in extra functions, that can later be replaced by code managing the "timer IC". With dividing your code this way you can write the rest of the logic without bothering about the timing part (after writing the `millis()` part as a "dummy").

For an oven timer the accuracy of the Arduinos clock should be ok, since it doesn't really matter, if it is a few seconds off. And for testing and writing the first code version it is also sufficient.

---

If the IC you are referring  to is a RTC (Real Time Clock) module, the code for it should be pretty simple to write. There are libraries for the most common RTCs. You might want to try the [Arduino Time library](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Time).